# Add class to a specific div when the bottom of a fixed div touches the top of this div, using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

After searching a lot, i didn't find a solution. My issue is this: I have a fixed top bar on my page and another div exactly below the fixed one the distance between the two div's is 150px-400px depending on the screen resolution.

What i want to do is to add a new class (some shadow) to the second div when the bottom of the fixed div touches the top of the second div. I know that i can use something like that:

```
$(function(){
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
   if($(this).scrollTop() > 150){
       $('.content').addClass('shadow');
   }else{
       $('.content').removeClass('shadow');
   }
}).scroll();
});
```

but it works only if the space between the 2 divs is 150px. How can i make this so my fixed div knows when it touches the top of the second div?

**[FIDLLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xd64V/14/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
  $(window).on('scroll', function(){

     var contentTop = $('.content').offset().top;
     var hHeight = $('.header').height();

     if($(this).scrollTop() > contentTop-hHeight){
         $('.content').addClass('shadow');
     }else{
         $('.content').removeClass('shadow');
     }
  }).scroll();
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Rheukala it worked perfect. PS Welcome to the community.